# Edit the innerhtml of a <li> to add an <i> tag with icon image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, controller, innerhtml

I have created a custom helper for tracking the current menu item in my MVC application and would now like to replace the icons I was using before the change and set the relevant href. Previously my list items looked like this:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Admin")"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Admin</a></li>            
<li><a class="active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
```

I now have created the generic menu item by using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MetaLearning.Helpers
{
  public static class MenuExtensions
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                         string text, string action,
                                         string controller,
                                         string iconClass,
                                         object routeValues = null,
                                         object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        li.InnerHtml = @"<a class=""active"" href=""/""><i class=""icon-home""></i>Home</a>";
        if (currentController.Contains(text))
        {
            li.InnerHtml = @"<a class=""active"" href=""/""><i class=""icon-home""></i>"+ text + "</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            li.InnerHtml = @"<a href=""/""><i class=""icon-home""></i>" + text + "</a>";
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set the href to the "/controller" and the name of the icon to iconClass. I have tried the following:

```
li.InnerHtml = @"<a class=""active"" href=""/""><i class=""icon-home""></i>"+ text + "</a>";
```

With this I am successfully showing the correct text but when I try to replace the href or icon class names with the relevant variables my string formation is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try **not** to concat strings with '+' operator this is not good behavior [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) you can read more yourself.

> How can I set the href to the "/controller" and the name of the icon
>   to iconClass.

```
 li.InnerHtml = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\"><i class=\"{2}\" /i>{1}</a>", controller, iconClass, text);
```